# How to correctly apply a cast on a variable so that it brings the methods that come with the cast?

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to make a more OOP friendly switch statement using interfaces and the like. I have created two interfaces, one called *IAction* and the other one called *ICase*. *IAction* interface includes one method called Do() which is implemented in my CaseX classes. *ICase* has one variable and it is Key, which returns the case number. Then I have two case classes, *CasePut* and *CaseGet* that implement both of those interfaces. To bundle them together I have written this class called *ConditionRequest* that stores both *CasePut* and *CaseGet* into a List.
To execute the switch procedure I have a method called Switch() inside the *ConditionRequest* class that uses LINQ to select the case the user needs. The problem arises in the Switch() method when I use `.Where` on `ICase<int?>` and then try to convert it to `IAction` using `.Select(p => p as IAction)`

I have not tried much other than changing up the syntax, but to no avail. I'm trying to understand why `IEnumerable<IAction> matches = Cases.Where(p => p.Key.Equals(key))
                .Select(p => p as IAction);`
returns null

line 34-44

```
    public interface IAction
    {
        void Do();
    }

    public interface ICase<TCase>
    {
        TCase Key { get; }
    }
```

line 44-66 - These are the cases I have defined

```
    public class CasePut : IAction, ICase<int?>
    {

        public int? Key { get { return 1; } }

        public void Do()
        {
            Request.Put putRequest = new Request.Put();
            putRequest.Request();
        }
    }
    public class CaseGet : IAction, ICase<int?>
    {
        public int? Key { get { return 2; } }

        public void Do()
        {
            Request.Get getRequest = new Request.Get();
            getRequest.Request();
        }
    }
```

line 67-91. This is the function that is the core of the OOP switch case, but it does not work properly, because I am trying to get the Do() method, by trying to convert `ICase<int?>` to `<IAction>`

```
   public abstract class SwitchCase<TCase>
    {
        protected List<ICase<TCase>> Cases { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConditionRequest : SwitchCase<int?>
    {
        public ConditionRequest()
        {
            Cases = new List<ICase<int?>>
            {
                new CasePut(),
                new CaseGet()
            };
        }

        public void Switch(int? key)
        {
            IEnumerable<IAction> matches = Cases.Where(p => p.Key.Equals(key))
                .Select(p => p as IAction);

            foreach (IAction match in matches)
                match.Do();
        }
    }
```

My expected result is to eventually make it so that through the conversion I can get access the class method Do(), because so far I can only get the Key of CaseX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following the code in your question, `matches` should either be an empty enumarable, or enumerate one or more `IAction`'s. Either your code in the question is not equivalent to your real code exhibiting the problem, or the problem is caused by something that is not shown in your question. I suggest you debug the code, especially paying attention to the `Cases` list and what its precise content is when the Linq query is being evaluated/executed by the foreach loop. Also, how did you check/came to the conclusion that your Linq query produced `null`? What effect did you observe?

Comment: Your code works, see by yourself: https://www.ideone.com/IoQEaZ

Comment: @elgonzo I just realized that it indeed is other functions giving me the error, namely the methods I execute in my Do() method. I realized it when I checked Kevin Gosse answer. Thanks! I feel so dumb